# Предварительная загрузка иконок font-awesome

Tags: html, css, fontawesome

Как сделать предварительную прогрузку иконок font awesome?

Проблема в том что когда открывается модальное окно бутстрап, все иконки находящиеся в нём начинают проявляться на глазах у юзера, а хотелось бы чтобы когда он открывал модалку они уже отображались

Comment: иконки подгружаются по cdn ?

Comment: @Айболит верно.

Comment: тогда подгружайте со свего сайта ... то есть от index.html